# How to Get E commerce Applications Data other than API?

Tags: api, web-scraping, e-commerce, amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

I am just wondering to know that is there are **other techniques available to access or fetch the data that data is not provided by the API** like Flipkart sellers Orders API doesn't provide image in his response and also they are not provided any other API for the same . Same case with Amazon they do not provide API for generating pdf for label etc for easyShipments. So is there other way to access the data that is not provided in API's.

> As I Google it they suggest that we can use Scrapping service for
>   that.

Would appreciate if anyone know that how we can access the data from any web application as scrapping is not the way to do that.I don't think scrapping is a good way or legal.

I have the appId and secret key for that even the authToken is also available. So please suggest me any technique that will help me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to hack into other people's data systems? :)

Comment: @tomliversidge not like that, i just want to know is there are some other ways as well for accessing the data  like API and i don't want to hack i just want to know because i have my client Id and secret key and authToken so on basis of that if i am trying to getting some information than i don't think that is wrong what do u say sir?

Comment: Did you ever get this answered elsewhere? I'm having similar questions that I think this could help me better research my own information.

Answer (score -3):

No.

APIs are provided for people to access data. What is exposed in the API is what data the company wants to expose.

HTML can be screen scraped but I wouldn't advise you do it for the reasons you mention, and there isn't really a contract there so things can arbitrarily change, breaking a screen scraping consumer

Other attempts to access data that isn't being provided to you would be equivalent to hacking.

You could try contacting the providers of the API and telling them your requirements - they might be able to advise or incorporate what you want into a future version of the API